# marklogic tree cache - shared resource?

Tags: marklogic

If I run a really dumb query that loads in a huge number of nodes into the expanded tree cache am I impacting other queries running on MarkLogic? In other words is the expanded tree cache a shared resource or is there portion allocated to my connection perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cache is shared.

Each cache is configured at the group level, and allocated at the host level. All concurrent queries on a given host share the same cache space. For the app-server this means the expanded-tree cache, while any forest lookups will use list cache and compressed-tree cache space.